# I'm trying detect if content pasted in input or was introduced from keyboard in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I almost reached my goal, only I'm not sure if everything works correctly here.

Look at the code itself you will understand what I mean:

```
const TodoApp = () => {
    const [value,setValue] = React.useState('');
  const [isPasted,setIsPasted] = React.useState(false);

  const onInput = (e) => {
    // browser returns valid result O_O
    console.log(isPasted);
    setValue(e.target.value);
  }

  const onPaste = (e) => {
    setIsPasted(true);
  }

  const onKeyUp = () => {
    setIsPasted(false);
  }


    return (
    <input 
      onInput={onInput}
      onPaste={onPaste}
      onKeyUp={onKeyUp}
      value={value}
    />
  )
}
ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Comment: I copy/pasted into a codesandbox. Other than the `onInput` should probably be `onChange`, this works. You probably don't need the key up handler if you move the `setIsPasted(false)` up in the input/change handler. Is there a specific issue you have?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? I don't understand it at all.

Comment: Actually not, but if the setState is working asynchronously, and the event loop almost simultaneously shoots onChange and onPaste event handlers, will this always work? (sorry for bad english) –

Comment: i cant use onChange event because in my case i'm using contentEditable div

Comment: All state updates from *a* render cycle are batch processed for the *next* render cycle.

Comment: I probably misunderstand something in React or in JS

Comment: anyway thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May not answer perfectly your actual question, but note that the [InputEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent) interface has a [`.inputType` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent/inputType) which will give you exactly this information, so if you don't target older browsers, you can only listen for the *input* event and check this property against `"insertFromPaste"` constant:

```
const onInput = (e) => {
  const isPasted = e.nativeEvent.inputType.startsWith("insertFromPaste");
  // ...
}
```

```js
const target = document.getElementById('target');
target.oninput = (evt) => {
  const isPasted = evt.inputType && evt.inputType.startsWith("insertFromPaste");
  target.classList.toggle('is-pasted', isPasted);
};
```

```css
.is-pasted { background-color: green; }
```

```html
<div contenteditable id="target">edit me</div>
```

Comment: Any reason why `insertFromPaste` becomes `insertFromText` on other phones?